# How do I get the whole error backtrace for rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2, allure, parallel-testing

Currently I am using
parallel tests
rspec
allure 0.8.0

After I run the tests I get the following error:

> RSpec::Core::MultipleExceptionError

I need the whole backtrace of the error. Is it some parameter that I need to pass to the command that I use to run and is there a permanent way so that it always prints the whole error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options, to define a helper with that attribute or in command line

```
## spec/spec_helper.rb
config.full_backtrace = true # false to dismiss
```

or in the command line

```
$ rspec spec/folder/your_spec.rb --backtrace
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error you need to find the specific test in the rspec log (scroll up). There you will see details about the issue.

In my case error was shown only on CI and I needed some time in order to figure out that everything I need is "hidden" somewhere in the super long output.